# Recreate replica when master is recreated

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a QA setup with a master and a replica. Both are AWS RDS MySQL. It's provisioned with Terraform and the gist is like this

```
data "aws_db_snapshot" "latest_prod_snapshot" {
  db_instance_identifier = var.production_instance_id
  most_recent            = true
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "qa_master" {
  apply_immediately                     = true
  snapshot_identifier                   = data.aws_db_snapshot.latest_prod_snapshot.id
  availability_zone                     = var.qa_master_zone
  instance_class                        = var.master_instance_class
  identifier                            = var.master_name
  parameter_group_name                  = var.parameter_group_name
  auto_minor_version_upgrade            = false
  multi_az                              = false
  performance_insights_enabled          = true
  performance_insights_retention_period = 7
  vpc_security_group_ids                = [var.security_group_id]
  option_group_name                     = var.option_group_name
  backup_retention_period               = 5
  skip_final_snapshot                   = true
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports       = ["audit", "error", "slowquery"]
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "qa_replica" {
  apply_immediately                     = true
  replicate_source_db                   = aws_db_instance.qa_master.id
  availability_zone                     = var.qa_replica_zone
  instance_class                        = var.replica_instance_class
  identifier                            = var.replica_name
  parameter_group_name                  = var.parameter_group_name
  auto_minor_version_upgrade            = false
  multi_az                              = false
  performance_insights_enabled          = true
  performance_insights_retention_period = 7
  vpc_security_group_ids                = [var.security_group_id]
  skip_final_snapshot                   = true
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports       = ["audit", "error", "slowquery"]
}
```

When I want to update it from a new snapshot, the master is always marked for recreation and replica for "change in place". But replication stops working after the update. Is there a workaround for that? Am I doing something weird here? Can I somehow force replica to recreate too?

So far I have been doing `terraform destroy` before doing the `terraform apply`.

Comment: Are you specifying the `identifier` or `identifier_prefix` for either of the databases? If so could you include that in your example please? It might make sense to fully flesh out your Terraform code here because there are some tricks that can be done based on the input parameters to the resources.

Comment: I'm using `identifier`. I've expanded the example, but there's not much to add.

Comment: Are you wedded to that identifier for the replica? Would you be happy with a generated one? The identifier is also used for the DNS record so unless you create a DNS record that CNAMEs/aliases that then you'd need to dynamically build the connection string instead of hardcoding it somewhere. If you can use any identifier then you could interpolate the `resource_id` attribute from the non replica instance. Then when the non replica instance is recreated (due to the snapshot changing) then the replica instance would also be recreated.

Comment: hmm, neat. I'll try it out, thank you. I do create a CNAME, so it looks viable at first glance. It will affect a lot of other places though, like all the log groups in Cloud Watch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger the replica being recreated you will need to have a `ForceNew` parameter on the replica resource change when the non replica changes.

With RDS there is a `resource_id` attribute that isn't normally surfaced in places people care about (you don't specify it, you don't use it to connect to it and it's not shown in the RDS console) but is different for each database instance (compared to the normal `identifier` which is specified).

This then brings us to the other part which is that that attribute needs to be in a `ForceNew` parameter on the replica resource. The obvious choices here are either the `identifier` or `identifier_prefix` parameters. The biggest impact here is that these are also used to identify the database instance from others but also used as part of the DNS address to connect to the database in the form of `${identifier}.${random_hash_of_account_and_region}.${region}.rds.amazonaws.com`. So if you're needing to connect to the instance then you'll either need to have the client discover the replica address as it will now contain the randomly generated `resource_id` of the non replica instance or you'll need to have Terraform create a DNS record that either CNAMEs or aliases the RDS address.

So in your case you might want something like this:

```
data "aws_db_snapshot" "latest_prod_snapshot" {
  db_instance_identifier = var.production_instance_id
  most_recent            = true
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "qa_master" {
  apply_immediately                     = true
  snapshot_identifier                   = data.aws_db_snapshot.latest_prod_snapshot.id
  availability_zone                     = var.qa_master_zone
  instance_class                        = var.master_instance_class
  identifier                            = var.master_name
  parameter_group_name                  = var.parameter_group_name
  auto_minor_version_upgrade            = false
  multi_az                              = false
  performance_insights_enabled          = true
  performance_insights_retention_period = 7
  vpc_security_group_ids                = [var.security_group_id]
  option_group_name                     = var.option_group_name
  backup_retention_period               = 5
  skip_final_snapshot                   = true
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports       = ["audit", "error", "slowquery"]
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "qa_replica" {
  apply_immediately                     = true
  replicate_source_db                   = aws_db_instance.qa_master.id
  availability_zone                     = var.qa_replica_zone
  instance_class                        = var.replica_instance_class
  identifier                            = "${var.replica_name}-${aws_db_instance.qa_master.resource_id}"
  parameter_group_name                  = var.parameter_group_name
  auto_minor_version_upgrade            = false
  multi_az                              = false
  performance_insights_enabled          = true
  performance_insights_retention_period = 7
  vpc_security_group_ids                = [var.security_group_id]
  skip_final_snapshot                   = true
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports       = ["audit", "error", "slowquery"]
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "example" {
  name = "example.com"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "replica_instance" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.example.zone_id
  name    = "qa-replica-database.${data.aws_route53_zone.example.name}"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = 60
  records = [aws_db_instance.replica_qa.address]
}
```

Now, if the production snapshot changes then the `qa_master` database instance resource will be recreated which will lead to the `qa_replica` database instance resource also being recreated and then the Route53 record for the `qa_replica` instance will be updated with the new address, allowing you to always connect to the replica at `qa-replica-database.example.com`.

Comment: I really hope there is a better way. I don't want my logs going into different log groups for every QA update.

Comment: You could technically use any `ForceNew` parameter. The only obvious other one is the `username` parameter which would normally be more annoying for that to contain an arbitrarily generated ID of the master I would think.